# How to customize the styles of the page in InAppBrowser

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I use the [Cordova InAppBrowser Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) to show page.

Is it possible to change the style of the page in InAppBrowser?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and can be done by [*insertCSS*](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md#insertcss) like

```
var ref = window.open(...);
ref.insertCSS(details, callback);
```

where the details is either a URL to stylesheet or the actual text (CSS) to inject. Callback is called after the styles have been inserted.

Comment: How do I know which css classes to modify? Not that I want to change the appearance of the InAppBrowser NOT its content!